# Android Studio : Operation is not supported for read-only collection

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I just update to Android Studio HedgeHog and for any project I have this message when compiling :

> "Operation is not supported for read-only collection"

It does not start compilation, it displays this message directly.

I am on Windows 11 pro.

I tried :

- invalid cache / restart
- create new projet in same/other default folder
- reinstall from scratch android studio

It worked by previous version of Android Studio Girafe.

Comment: did you find any solution? @tonio

Comment: Yes ! Menu -> File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings.. worked for me !

Comment: I have the same problem and I tried all the solutions, but the problem is still exist

Answer (score 7):

I solved it by unchecking this in the Experimental Configs.

> Settings > Experimental > Trace Gradle Import with profile

If that doesn't work, try to uncheck other experimental options.

Answer (score 5):

Go to "Android Studio -> Files -> Settings -> Experimental" and disable the "Trace Gradle with the Import" check box. This occurred after updating to Hedgehog.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

I Did `Menu -> File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings...`

After restart and reinitializion of Android Studio, opened project again and it's working OK now.

Update: This will reset all settings and plugins. Try with other solutions first like disabling "Trace Gradle Import with profile" before doing that.

Comment: For me this is not working! do you have other option, I have tried everything from answers in this post but none is working. If i use canary build it is working though

Comment: Sorry, not. Had problems for long time, and this helped me. Other answer with trust location could be also possible solution.

Comment: I just deleted my android studio seetings from appdata folder, which created entirely new AS settings and it worked.

Comment: This works for me. Basically you have to reset Android Studio and make sure it asks you if to **trust the project** you want to open.

Comment: For me it works

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that is because the project had been imported from the previous version of the Android Studio, but the studio did not suggest 'trust' it.

Go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Trusted Locations and add the project's parent folder to the trusted locations list.

If that didn't help, try to re-import the project (make sure that parent directory is added to trusted locations).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all means suggested by the above posts, none of them work for me. Stupid upgrading has to restore back to the previous version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).